# How is $\log (a-b) = -\log (a+b)$ true?

Tags: complex-analysis

My complex analysis textbook asserts the following: $\log (a-b) = -\log (a+b)$

What is going on? How is this possible?

It says:

"Dividing by i and utilizing $\log (10-3\sqrt{3})=-\log (10+3\sqrt{3})$"

Comment: It's not true in general. Please provide more context.

Comment: Is it possible to give more context or which textbook it is? Quite likely there is a typo of some sort here, but there might be something in the context we cannot see.

Comment: It's generally not true. Take $a=2$ and $b=1$, that would imply $-\log (3) = 0$, which is certainly not true.

Comment: @Clayton, me too, the *second* time I do it.

Comment: Are you sure it is not that $\log(a-ib)=-\log(a+ib)$ when $a^2+b^2=1$ (that is, $a\pm ib$ is on the unit circle)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\log(a-b)=-\log(a+b)\iff \log(a-b)+\log(a+b)=0$$

If both logarithm remain defined this implies & is implied by

$$\log(a^2-b^2)=0\iff a^2-b^2=1$$

Comment: +$1$ for answer the question of "How is this possible?" Now if only we could find which textbook it is and some context surrounding the (possible) typo.